# How can I create a Django form out of a Model with an intermediary model? (I.E, a box with many products, as in, 10 products A, 5 products B)

Tags: python, django, forms, model

First of all, the specifics of the project I'm working on are essentially the same as the example shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237686/how-to-associate-quantity-amount-in-djangos-many-to-many-relationship), so I think it's easier to explain what I want to achieve using them.

Background from the mentioned question:

Think of a Box model that contains products, using an intermediary model, we can store not only multiple products but also different quantities of each product. Here is the code from the answer to the question mentioned above:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    boxName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = False)
    product_set = models.ManyToManyField(ProductSet)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.boxName

class ProductSet(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.PROTECT)

class Product(models.Model):
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    productDescription = models.TextField(blank=True)
    productPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=0, default=0)

    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        ordering = ['-productName']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productName
```

This solution solves the model set up for what I want to achieve. In my specific case, the box model is a project model, and the products model is a materials model, essentially I want to store projects, which reference various materials required for said project, so each material will have different quantities.

As a quick example: if there's a cake project, the materials can be 5 eggs and 1 lb of flour mix. So, storing not only materials but quantities of those materials achieves what I'm shooting for.

Going back to the Box, ProductSet, and Product example.

The part that I can't seem to figure out is the ModelForm of the Box model. I'm aware I can use the ModelMultipleChoice field which would show all the product_sets, but the thing is I would need to create the instances of product_set within the same form, to then save the box model with the created product_sets.

For example, the BoxForm would have the box name, and the products, which would be a query set of the ProductSet model, but the whole point is to create a ProductSet instance to save on the Box. In other words, if I already created a box that has 5 units of product A, and then I want to create another box, in the box form I want to have another form(?) to input what product I want and how many of them, not a list of the product-quantity pairs I already used.

If you could explain in detail what would the proper solution be, I'd appreciate it as I'm still learning about Django :)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't map naturally onto a ModelForm, then don't use a ModelForm. Use a vanilla Form or Formset to acquire the data from the user and then, in `form_valid`, create the objects as requested/ required. Do this inside a transaction so you either get all, or none, of the objects created.

If you find you need to raise errors inside `form_valid`, then you can.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
   # ... further validation that's hard to do inside the form itself
   if (something):
       form.add_error('fieldname', 'Error message') 
       # form is no longer valid
   
   # carry on validating. bear in mind that form.cleaned_data['fieldname']
   # will no longer exist after adding an error against it.
   ...

   # can we go ahead?
   if not form.is_valid():
       return super().form_invalid( form)

   # now do stuff to the database
   with transaction.atomic():
       # create and/or update objects
       ...

       return redirect( 'app:name', args... )
```

Note: I'm assuming the use of  Class-based views, but the technique ought to generalize.

Comment: How would you recommend to go about creating the actual form though? Since it'd need to have a list of the products and a linked quantity input for each, that's where Im struggling 

Comment: I thought from your description, a Formset of (product, quantity) forms. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/